# Setting up a SeekBar programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, seekbar

for a past few hours I'm trying to set a width of a SeekBar by code (it has to be set by the configuration file). I was trying to set it via `"seekBar[i].SetMinimumWidth(600);"`, I was also trying to do this with "ShapeDrawable", but it wasn't working, here is my example how I was doing that:

```
SeekBar sb = new SeekBar(this);
            sb.SetX(720 / 2);
            sb.SetY(1280 / 2);
            ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
            thumb.SetIntrinsicHeight(64);
            thumb.SetIntrinsicWidth(600);
            sb.SetThumb(thumb);
            sb.SetBackgroundColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
```

I was also thinking about some kind of style, but I'm not sure that this is possible to do this this way. How do I set a width of a seekbar by code? 
I also have to set the min and max value of SeekBar, but i have no idea how to set those properites with code. I know, that I can simply lock it by if statment like this:

```
sb.ProgressChanged += (object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    if (e.FromUser)
                    {
                       if (e.Progress < localSliderMax && e.Progress > localSliderMin)
                         //SomeWork
                    }
                };
```

But what if i will need for example a min value a -1, or max 255? It won't work like this. Any solution how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I set a width of a seekbar by code?

You can set it for example like this:

```
sb.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(900, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

900 here in the code is the width of `SeekBar`. Please refer to the [ViewGroup.LayoutParams Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Views.ViewGroup+LayoutParams/) for more information about the layout of control.

> But what if i will need for example a min value a -1, or max 255?

You can't define the minimum value to -1. It is 0.

To set 255, you can set the value to `Max` property of your `SeekBar`, here is a sample:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    RelativeLayout mlayout = new RelativeLayout(this)
    {
        LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent)
    };

    SeekBar sb = new SeekBar(this)
    {
        LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(900, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
        Max = 255,
    };

    mlayout.AddView(sb);
    SetContentView(mlayout);
    sb.ProgressChanged += Sb_ProgressChanged;
}

private void Sb_ProgressChanged(object sender, SeekBar.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var progress = e.Progress;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(progress);
}
```

To style the `SeekBar`, since there're too many possiblities, I don't know what exactly do you need, thus I only set `Width` and `Max` value from code behind which are specified in your question.

Comment: That pretty much all I need.Thanks!